# When I loaded file/s into Snowflake Stage i see difference in number of bytes loaded in snowflake stage compared to the files in my local system

Tags: file, size, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, difference, stage

When I loaded file/s into Snowflake Stage i see difference in number of bytes  loaded compared to the files in my local system, does anyone know the reason for this issue ? How it can be resolved.

File size in my local is 16622146 bytes, after loaded into stage it shows as 16622160 bytes, i have checked with .csv and .txt file types. (I know .txt file is not supported in snowflake).
I compressed the file and loaded into snowflake stage using snowsql using put command.

Comment: Are you using auto_compress in your PUT statement? Would you be using the file size for any purpose?

Comment: I don't know whether this is an answer or not, but when you PUT a file, Snowflake encrypts it on your local machine before posting to internal stage.  So, the bytes in the stage are an encrypted byte count, where your local copy isn't.

Comment: @Abhi  Reddy, I have kept auto_compress =false, when i check  MD5 on local with the file on stage, they don't match..at least that should match.

Comment: @Mike Walton, when I compare MD5 they don't match, how I can say the file loaded up is same as file on my local, looks like bytes difference causing the difference in the MD5.

Comment: MD5 would be different if one file was encrypted and one wasn't.  Have you tried loading it and seeing whether the data is the same?

Comment: @Mike Walton, Data is same, but when i do bulk load thru python connector or snowsql, i just  get MD5 of the file loaded and compared with local file and say they are good and this i want to do programmatically and I cannot check each file manually .

Comment: If you get a non-error response from the PUT command you can safely assume the file is uploaded and has the same data, why do you want to additional checks? The files aren't the same that's why the hash doesn't match.

Answer (score 0):

When loading small files from the local file system, snowflake automatically compresses the file. Please try that option.

Refer to this section of the documentation
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-prepare.html#data-file-compression

This will help you to avoid any data corruption related issues during the compression.

Thanks
Balaji